# I animated my 2D game but my character doesn't move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

I've been following Brackeys tutorials to make a 2D game and right now I'm on animation. The animation plays he attacks, the sprite flips both directions, etc.. but still stuck in the same spot. I've watched and rewatched the tutorial and can't figure it out.

Before adding animation everything worked perfectly. He moved across the screen, he jumped, etc.. So i know that him not moving is directly tied to trying to animating

This is my playermovement script I made from following his tutorial.

```
public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Animator animator;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool Attack = false;

    void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            animator.SetBool("Attack", true);
            Attack = false;
        }
    }
    public void OnLanding ()     
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
    }



    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, jump);
        jump = false;

    }
}
```

This is my character controller

```
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
    [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
    [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

    const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
    private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
    const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

    [Header("Events")]
    [Space]

    public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

    public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
    private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (OnLandEvent == null)
            OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();

        if (OnCrouchEvent == null)
            OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
        m_Grounded = false;

        // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
        // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
            {
                m_Grounded = true;
                if (!wasGrounded)
                    OnLandEvent.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }


    public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
    {
        // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
        if (!crouch)
        {
            // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
            {
                crouch = true;
            }
        }

        //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {

            // If crouching
            if (crouch)
            {
                if (!m_wasCrouching)
                {
                    m_wasCrouching = true;
                    OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(true);
                }

                // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
                move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

                // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
            } else
            {
                // Enable the collider when not crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;

                if (m_wasCrouching)
                {
                    m_wasCrouching = false;
                    OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(false);
                }
            }

            // Move the character by finding the target velocity
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

            // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
            if (move < 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
            else if (move > 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
        }
        // If the player should jump...
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }
    }


    private void Flip()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your console show any errors? Maybe you're not correctly configuring the `CharacterController2D` in your Character.

Comment: Show some work on editor as well. How did you assign character controller or animator?

Comment: is it intentional that you do `animator.SetBool("Attack", true);` but `Attack = false;`? Also please add details about your animator and transitions setup

Comment: @b.galerani I have no errors.

Comment: @SaadAnees I assigned them how Brackeys tutorial told me to. The character controller is attached to my playermovement script just like in his video same goes for the animator.

Comment: @derHugo Thats something I'm working on separate to the issue that I'm currently trying to figure out. Also I followed brackeys tutorial step by step so I set everything up exactly like this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8)

Comment: Which video exactly? please post the video link. I cannot watch every video in his channel.

Comment: i posted the link in my last comment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late to help the OP now, but I had exactly the same issue today and finally figured it out.
I was scaling the main object for some of my animations. To fix it I went in and removed any scaling of the main container object and instead scaled the internal objects individually and now the flipping works.

Clearly the animation scaling interferes with the controller flip scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code but make shure you Character has a 2DRigidbody and a 2DBoxcollider and watch out that the script has the name "Character2DController"
I hope it will help you ;)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Character2DController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 1;
    public float JumpForce = 1;
    public Animator animator;
    private bool facingRight; 

    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
    void Start()
    {
        facingRight = true;
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
            
    void Update()

    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
       {
           transform.localScale = new Vector2 (-1.5f, transform.localScale.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.5f, transform.localScale.y);
        }

        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat("Movement Speed", Mathf.Abs(movement));

        {

        }

        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.001f)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }`enter code here`
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You may check the values from `horizontalMove` while debugging or add a `Debug.Log` statement to check its value while testing, just to make sure that the value is what is expected.

Also ensure that `controller` was assigned.